# How to copy or write an entire file to another file using 'BUFSIZ' in C program?

Tags: c, file-io

Trying to read a file and writing to another new file using C's BUFSIZ. But the reading loop goes to infinitely. Where is the issue and how to fix it.

```
[cpy.c]
// Copy from file 1 to file 2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For 'exit'
#include <stdarg.h> // For va_args

#include "unistd.h" // For 'open'  (for Windows Only)
#include <fcntl.h>  // For 'O_RDONLY'

#define PERMS 0666

void error(char *, ...);

long getFileSize(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ssize_t n;
    int f1, f2;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    long writtenBytes = 0;
    float toMb = 1024 * 1024;
    float percent;

    if (argc < 3) {
        error("Usage: cpy <from.ext> <to.ext>");
    }

    // Opening source file.
    if ((f1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1)
        error("Unable to read a %s file.", argv[1]);

    long fileSize = getFileSize(argv[1]); // in Bytes
    float fileSizeMb = fileSize / toMb;
    printf("Source file (Size: %.2f Mb): %s\n", fileSizeMb, argv[1]);

    // Create a Destination file
    if ((f2 = creat(argv[2], PERMS)) == -1)
        error("Unable to create a destination file (%s).", argv[2]);

    // Read a source file.
    while ((n = read(f1, buf, BUFSIZ)) != -1) // > 0 // **TO FIX #1** 
        if (write(f2, buf, n) != n)
            error("While writing data to (%s) file! Please try again.", argv[2]);
        else {
            //printf("\r%d Bytes are readed now.", n);
            writtenBytes += BUFSIZ; //(long) n;  // **TO FIX #2** 

            percent = (float) writtenBytes / fileSize;
            printf("\r%.2f%% (%.2f / %.2f Mb) is completed", percent, writtenBytes/(toMb*100.0), fileSizeMb);
            //fflush(stdout);
        }

    printf("\nFile (%s) is copied.", argv[2]);
    return 0;
}

// Get The size of the file.
long getFileSize(char *filepath)
{
    FILE *fh = fopen(filepath, "r");

    if (fh == NULL) {
        error("FILESIZE: Unable to open a \"%s\" file.\n", filepath);
        return 0;
    }

    // Go to end of the file.
    fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filesize = ftell(fh);
    // Set back seek to beginning of the file, for next time read.
    fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return filesize;
}

// Print an Error msg and die
void error(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: ");
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    va_end(args);

    exit(1);
}
```

Aim is to be, read and write it to a new file and show the 'Percentage' of completion along with bytes which is already written at this moment.

As a guess, the Line to be fixed is marked as, '** TO FIX ##' ** inside of the code.

- Code "TO FIX #1" - While using '> 0', it's not actually writing anything.
- Code "TO FIX #2" - I think, it should be 'n' instead of
  'BUFSIZ' in order to get the exact bytes have to be written at end of
  completion.

And finally, '90 Mb' of file is always writing to '11 KB' only, after the 'Ctrl+C'.

Compile: `gcc -o bin/cpy cpy.c -Wall`

Run    : cpy from.mp4 to.mp4

Env    : Codeblocks 17.12, Windows 10 64Bit

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: `getFileSize()` never closes `fh`.  There is no "next time read" for `fh`.

Comment: Add error checks.  Does either `fseek();` or `ftell()` return an error?

Comment: `writtenBytes/(toMb*100.0)` is suspicious.  Perhaps `writtenBytes/toMb`

Comment: "Code "TO FIX #1" - While using '> 0'" is a good idea.  Why have you not used it?

Comment: `!= 1` is not semantically the same as `> 0` because the value could be zero.  Does it really go into the loop infinitely of rather just never exist the loop - which may not be quite the same thing.  What is the output while in the loop - since the code outputs text of every iteration?  That is your debug information but you choose not to tell us!  You would do better perhaps to use the Code::Blocks  debugger.

Comment: Surely `percent = (float) writtenBytes * 100f / fileSize;` ?

Comment: Why not just use `fstat()` to get the file size?

Comment: Don't use `float` (or even `double`) for file sizes.  A `float` can barely represent 1048576 accurately.  Use integers.

Answer (score 0):

When `read`(2) hits end of file, it [returns 0](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read), not -1.

Your code hits end of file, and from that moment `read` returns 0, but you would only stop on -1.